# Get mouse buttons in entire Windows screen with a npm module

Tags: npm, mouseevent, electron

I am looking for a module that could help me to get mouse buttons in screen (the entire screen) for my electron app.

Can you help me ?
I tried hundreds but all are linked to the "window" parameter which doesn't exist in electron main.js script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to get the mouse clicks within the window of your application? Or *anywhere* on screen, even outside your app?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and I would like mouse buttons state in the entire screen even outside my app.

Comment: UP pleaaaaaaase